# Is it possible to use cratering processes to measure the yield strength $Y$ of a material?

Tags: astronomy, aerodynamics

I have some questions about the paper

- The scaling of impact processes in planetary sciences. K.A. Holsapple, [*Annu. Rev. Earth Planet. Sci.* **21**, 333 (1993)](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.ea.21.050193.002001); available as an [author eprint on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4688454_The_Scaling_of_Impact_Processes_in_Planetary_Sciences).

and I have some questions about how applicable it is to measuring yield strengths of materials.

If anyone has read the paper (and hopefully also understood it), do you think it is possible to extract values for diameter & depth of a crater from a laboratory experiment and then: assuming that the shape of the crater is a cone with its tip cut off calculate the volume of the crater, $V$, which appears in equations (1, 2 & especially 3)?

From there, is it possible to use these equations to calculate the yield strength $Y$ of the material strength, and hopefully go on to categorise different target material based on their yield strength?

I want to go on with this plan which would require me to spend time building the basics needed to understand the paper, but I am looking for guidance since I am not sure about the validity of the plan.

Comment: Add links to the description of the database and to the CRATERING DATABASE https://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2004/pdf/1779.pdf http://keith.aa.washington.edu/craterdata/scaling/index.htm

Comment: I've edited your question title to one that's more reflective of the core of the question. You're welcome to edit it further, but keep [these principles](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Could one calculate yield strengths from cratering? Probably. Would it be a good way of doing it? That depends.

[While tensile testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_(engineering)#Testing) of yield is the standard method, indentation testing is popular and in a sense a case of making tiny craters. However, it seems to be less exact than tensile testing: do you believe cratering will provide better information than the other methods?

It seems to me that one need to evaluate both the required precision, the cost of doing it (time, money, annoyance), and whether the testing domain is sufficiently similar to the Holsapple cases to be applicable - if I remember the paper right it does cover a lot of scales so this might be fairly OK, but one should always check. Dropping a marble into sand on a lab floor is different from a TNT device on top of rocks on a shooting range in terms of material homogenity and fluid dynamics.

(My inner pyrotechnics enthusiast of course shouts "go ahead! make some craters! because it is coool!", but that is for entertainment rather than science.)

Comment: While Holsapple does look like a typo, it's the correct spelling of the name. The blame probably goes to a careless immigration official ;-).

Comment: @anders                                                                                                                                              
  1) Could you explain what are scales ? 2)The purpose of this is not industrial at all. I am only writing a research paper thus I need a certain degree of precision but nothing really practical. Do you know if the values for Y are on a macroscopic level or not because it would make it easier to achieve precise results ? And do you know what the percentage uncertainty may be like ?

Comment: @anders                                                                                                                          If you think that it is plausible to measure the Yield strength could please outline mathematically a way of how I would do that because I am not familiar with dimensional analysis which seems to be the math that is used in the equations of this paper ?